# Keep Rebooting After Installing Fake GPS For Pokemon GO (I Think It's Not Bootloop)

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, gps, reboot, pokemon-go

Today I'm installing the Fake GPS app for Pokemon GO, I watch the tutorial from here: [Trik akali GPS pokemon GO - Fake GPS POKEMON GO trick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-GYuBQURXk)

Well, at the first try, I don't have any issue.. but, after a few hours it got rebooted by itself.

Just like this: [My Rebooting Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5NI0AoXya0)

-Samsung Galaxy Ace 3 GT-S2720 Android 4.2.2

Comment: Turn on Mock locations to set gps, Then turn it back off before opening Pokemon

Comment: Okay then I'll try

Comment: My reboot problem's not solved :3

Comment: @FerdiRamadhan You can fix this rebooting issue all you like, but do keep in mind that Niantic will catch on almost instantly that you're spoofing your GPS, and will softban you from the game. So, there's that.

Comment: Perhaps a little OT but how did you get Pokemon go to work on 4.2? Isn't 4.4 the minimum required version?

Comment: Lol i got the unlocked apk from youtube, and using apk editor app

Comment: In fact, the code it uses makes the app compatible even on JB. Heh, all business.

Answer (score 0):

Just factory reset my phone *frustated =w= And I think, I know what's the problem that made my phone rebooting like that. The Fake GPS app itself, I've been testing it after a few factory reset.. well i think it's a bug =w=

My advice:

**Never Install Fake GPS**